# how to set focus for elements in a spring based application

Tags: forms, validation, user-interface, spring-mvc, custom-errors

I have a spring application where i validate all validations in custom spring validator class.

My form has nearly 15 fields.If there is a error in the last field , how to set the focus to that element.

Does spring tags support that. Any technical ideas ? Currently i display my error messages near the fields itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use [spring:bind](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.5/taglib/) tag to determine whether a field or the whole model object has error and the overall status of the object after processing (submission).

```
<spring:bind path="user.username">
    <input id="inputId" type="text" name="${status.expression}" value="${status.value}"/>
    <c:if test="${status.error}">
        <c:forEach items="${status.errorMessages}" var"error">
            <span class="field-error">${error}</span>
        </c:forEach>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById('inputId').focus();
        </script>
    </c:if>
</spring:bind>
```

**Note:**

- The `status` variable is exposed by the `spring:bind` tag.
- The javascript part will focus the element when the specific field
  has validation errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can set [autofocus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) to all fields that have an error, but your browser will only autofocus (and scroll) to the first one.

```
<spring:bind path="someFieldName">
  <input type="text" name="someFieldName" value="${status.value}" ${status.error?'autofocus="autofocus"':''} />
</spring:bind>
```

You can't use spring's `<form:input />` here as it doesn't work with conditional attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this:

```
    <spring:bind path="*">
        <c:if test="${status.error}"> 
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.onload = function(){
                    document.getElementById('${status.errors.fieldErrors[0].field}').focus();
                };
            </script>  
        </c:if>
    </spring:bind>
```

If there is an error it will find the first fieldError and its id and set the focus on that element

> forgot to say that the beauty is that you don't need to put this code next to every input. One time is enough per jsp